# Substring of varying length after a specific character

Tags: javascript, string, substring

I'm trying to grab part of a string that looks like **"A_1234_5678, B_2345_678, C_3456_78"** where the first part of the list item is a category and the part after the first underscore is data I need in some form (3456_78 or 3456 78).

They are always in the same order, but not always present. 
For example, it could also look like **"A_1234_5678, C_3456_7890"** as well. But let's say I need the data after C_. It's always the same order, but not always the same index in the list. Also, the data is not always the same length. So the length of the data varies and the index at which it starts varies.

Is there some way to do this? Preferably javascript so I can use it in a website with `<script>`. I've looked at split, substr, and tried indexOf, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely.  I would sugest using regex.

```
var stringToParse = 'C_3456_7890';
var returnArray = stringToParse .match(/^([A-Z])_([0-9_]*)$/);
```

This will have the category letter at index 1 of the array, and the data at index 2. It should work as long as the category is always one capital letter and the index is only numbers and underscores.  If you let me know more about the possible options I can update my response

EDIT

to help with more than one item in a list, you should split it on the commas first

```
var stringToTest = "A_1234_5678, B_2345_678, C_3456_78"
var arrayOfStrings = stringToTest.split(',')
for (var i = 0; i<arrayOfStrings.length; i++){
  var returnArray = arrayOfStrings[i].match(/^\s*([A-Z])_([0-9_]*)\s*$/);
  console.log(returnArray);
}
```

replace the console log with whatever code you need to use to work with the data and category and you will be good to go.

2nd EDIT

A suggestion of the code to use in the loop:

```
if (returnArray[1] == 'C'){
  var foundData = returnArray[2];
  break;
}
```

So the full code would look something like

```
var stringToTest = "A_1234_5678, B_2345_678, C_3456_78"
var arrayOfStrings = stringToTest.split(',')
var foundData = false;
for (var i = 0; i<arrayOfStrings.length; i++){
  var returnArray = arrayOfStrings[i].match(/^\s*([A-Z])_([0-9_]*)\s*$/);
  if (returnArray[1] == 'C'){
    foundData = returnArray[2];
    break;
  }
}
console.log(foundData !== false ? foundData : 'Sorry, no matching index found!')
```

you can then put this into a function and take the required category as an argument. extending the functionality

Answer (score 0):

```
function getByCategory(data, category) {
    return data.split(',').map(function(x) { 
        return x.trim();
    }).filter(function(y) {
        return y.indexOf(category) === 0;
    }).shift().replace(category + '_', '');
}
```

to be used as

```
var data = getByCategory('A_1234_5678, B_2345_678, C_3456_78', 'B'); //2345_678
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/sb77sbp1/)